# Android Audio Cropping by choosing a media from gallery within a app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement audio cropping functionality within my app, user can select choose media from gallery and then select the duration upto 15 seconds which they can listen and crop within my app. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think there is a native audio crop

Comment: There are lots of this kind of apps on Play Store, hence this is possible. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Can you provide a sample application name?